# Custom Drawn UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I need to have a circular UIButton that draws a custom color in the middle, along with an outer ring that is drawn as the default tint color (similar to a UIColorWell).

[image]

I've tried a few different approaches:

1. Using a multicolor SFSymbol: This would be an elegant solution, but as far as I can tell there's no way to apply the tint color to just a part of the image while setting the center to be a custom color.  Either the entire image is tinted, or the image is drawn as the default colors set in the symbol file. Also, I need to support iOS 14, while the new hierarchical options that *may* allow me to accomplish this were added to iOS 15.
2. Setting various layer properties (ie, cornerRadius, borderColor, etc): This works and may be a decent fallback solution, but I'm unable to get the look that I'm going for (namely, having a transparent ring between the outer border and inner colored circle).

If there's a way to use either of the above options, please educate me! Either one seems like a better solution than:

3. Overloading the draw function: This is the option I'm going with at the moment, as it allows me to have complete creative control over the look of the button.  The rest of this post will be regarding this method.

So far I was able to get the button to be drawn exactly as I wanted.  However, I am unable to figure out how to draw the button appropriately with regards to various state changes.

For example, if a popover is displayed, all of the normal buttons are automatically redrawn as disabled.  My custom button, however, isn't redrawn so I am unable to respond to the state change.

[image]

Same thing with tapping on the button - normal buttons are briefly shown in an emphasized color but my custom button doesn't respond.

Does someone have an example as to how to support overriding UIButton drawing with various states?

Comment: What about setting its `setImage(for:)` or `setBackgroundImage(for:)` instead and populate it with the drawn images? If you don't do anyother stuff custom, there is no need to subclass it in reality... Else, maybe with a KVO (if possible), or just override of its `state` property, you might reflect the redrawing?

Comment: I've tried drawing to an image and then setting the image on the button.  Unfortunately, unless template images are used, I don't get the automatic re-coloring and therefore still need to know when the state has changed.  I've also tried overloading the various state properties in UIButton (ie, isEnabled) but those aren't called unless the state is actually set (ie, not when a popover is displayed). At this point I'm left with re-thinking my design as I don't see a way to get what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired behavior by overriding `tintColorDidChange` in order to trigger a redraw of the button. Now I am able to draw the outer ring in the correct color (including grayed out when a popover is displayed) while maintaining the desired inner color.